# How to get appropriate decimal/double currency value with decimal point?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I get to the proper value of the the amount entered in textfield? Assuming my dollar value is 50.05, I noticed that when I try to access:

```
bindingManager.text.decimal
```

I get 5005. What am I doing wrong to not get 50.05?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var bindingManager = TextBindingManager(amount: 0)
    var decimal: Decimal { bindingManager.text.decimal / pow(10, Formatter.currency.maximumFractionDigits) }
    var maximum: Decimal = 999_999_999.99
    @State private var lastValue: String = ""
    @State private var locale: Locale = .current {
        didSet { Formatter.currency.locale = locale }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField(bindingManager.text, text: $bindingManager.text)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)  // this will keep the text aligned to the right
                .onChange(of: bindingManager.text) { string in
                    if string.decimal > maximum {
                        self.bindingManager.text = lastValue
                    } else {
                        self.bindingManager.text = decimal.currency
                        lastValue = self.bindingManager.text
                    }
                    return
                }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            Formatter.currency.locale = locale
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class TextBindingManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = ""
    var amount: Decimal = .zero
    init(amount: Decimal) {
        self.amount = amount
        self.text = Formatter.currency.string(for: amount) ?? "$0.00"
        
    }
}
```

---

```
fileprivate extension Formatter {
    static let currency: NumberFormatter = .init(numberStyle: .currency)
}

extension NumberFormatter {
    convenience init(numberStyle: Style) {
        self.init()
        self.numberStyle = numberStyle
    }
}

extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var digits: Self { filter (\.isWholeNumber) }
}

extension String {
    var decimal: Decimal { Decimal(string: digits) ?? 0 }
}

extension Decimal {
    var currency: String { Formatter.currency.string(for: self) ?? "" }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand you are disposing non-digit characters like `.` in your `digits`?

Comment: Add another var inside the String extension and use this ```var decimalString: String { components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted).joined() }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to divide the decimal value by the number of maximum fraction digits. Same as it is being done with the decimal instance property of your ContentView:

```
var decimal: Decimal { bindingManager.text.decimal / pow(10, Formatter.currency.maximumFractionDigits) }
```

---

```
.onChange(of: bindingManager.text) { string in
    if string.decimal > maximum {
        self.bindingManager.text = lastValue
    } else {
        self.bindingManager.text = decimal.currency
        lastValue = self.bindingManager.text
    }
    print("decimal", decimal)
    return
}
```

---

This will print

> decimal 0.05
> decimal 0.5
> decimal 5
> decimal 50.05